# Adding another robot model and controlling it

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi
After I unpinned the drc robot and it fell down because my control wasn't right, I want to try again with out starting gazebo again. I tried deleting the model and putting in another one but then it liiks as if the control node isn't controlling it. any ideas how should I do it?
Thanks
Nachum

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/218/adding-another-robot-model-and-controlling-it/) by [Nachum](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/50/nachum/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 35 on 2012-11-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Quoting from @hsu's comment:

actually, I recommend Edit -> Reset Model Poses, this way, there is no need to restart all the controller components.

---

Originally posted by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) with karma: 1414 on 2013-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You could try resetting your world by Edit -> Reset World.

---

Originally posted by [logicalguy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/24/logicalguy/) with karma: 73 on 2012-11-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) on 2012-11-16**:
actually, I recommend Edit -> Reset Model Poses, this way, there is no need to restart all the controller components.

**Comment by [asomerville](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/65/asomerville/) on 2012-11-30**:
@logicalguy That vote should put you over the karma threshold for voting. Do what I did and use your limited votes on the best answers and question to help seed healthy community participation.